# How to exclude columns for SimpleImputer in Make_columns_transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Please advise how can I include all columns except categorical feature column for SimpleImputer without specifying all the column name? Having error when I tried to using dataframe with drop().

```
ct = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(),['ocean_proximity']),
    (SimpleImputer(strategy='median'),housing.drop(labels=['ocean_proximity'],axis=1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `df.select_dtypes(exclude=['dtype'])`
Here is the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

```
ct = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(),['ocean_proximity']),
    (SimpleImputer(strategy='median'),housing.drop(labels=['ocean_proximity'],axis=1).select_dtypes(exclude=['categorical']),axis=1)))
```